# Changing Screen using TabbedPanel Item | Kivy | Python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am using kivy to create an app which will be having multiple screens, I am using Screen Manager component to manage the screens.

```
<AppScreenManager>:
    Screen:
        name: "HomeScreen"
        HomeScreenLayout:

    Screen:
        name: "ImageScreen"
        ImageScreenMenu:
```

My home screen has a tabbed Panel

```
<HomeScreenLayout>:
    rows: 3
    TabbedPanel:
        tab_pos: 'top_mid'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        do_default_tab: False
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "File"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: "50dp"
                spacing: "20dp"
                size: root.width, root.height
                Image:
                    id: my_image
                    source: ""
                FileChooserListView:
                    id: fileChooser
                    on_selection: root.selected_file(fileChooser.selection)


        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "Cut"
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "Blur"
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "Filters"
```

I wanted to use the click of a tabbed Panel item in order to change the screen and that screen will have its own tabbed panel. In the documentation and other guides i have read they have used button to change the screen.

I wanted the click of a tabbedPanelItem to result in a screen change, I have tried using on_press attribute but it docent seem to work

```
TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "Cut"
            on_press: root.current = "ImageScreen"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabbedPanelItem` is a `ToggleButton`, so you can use `on_state` like this:

```
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Cut"
        on_state: if self.state == "down": app.root.current = "ImageScreen"
```

Note that you will never be able to see any content in that `TabbedPanelItem` if you use the tab to change to another `Screen`.